# Show that always A.M. (arithmetic multiplicity) = G.M. (geometric multiplicity) for symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The proof is quite trivial for non-repetitive eigenvalues, but how to show that A.M. = G.M. for repetitive eigenvalues of symmetric matrices without using diagonalizability argument.

I saw some places that it could be proved by perturbation analysis, but can it be done by any other way? If not then can you elaborate how to show it using perturbation analysis.

Comment: Symmetric matrices are diagonalizable..

Comment: Yes, but my question was how to prove AM=GM without using diagonalizability argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ be symmetric, $\lambda$ an arbitrary eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $\mathbb{N} \ni n \geq 2$. We have to show $\ker(T-\lambda) = \ker((T-\lambda)^n)$.

"$\subseteq$": This inclusion is trivial.

"$\supseteq$": Assume x is in $\ker((T-\lambda)^n) \setminus \ker(T-\lambda)$, hence $(T-\lambda)^n x = 0$ and $(T - \lambda)x \neq 0$. This yields, with usage of $T = T^*$:

$\langle (T-\lambda)^{n-1}x,(T-\lambda)^{n-1}x \rangle = \langle (T-\lambda)^{n}x,(T-\lambda)^{n-2}x \rangle = 0$ and by this $(T-\lambda)^{n-1}x = 0$. By iterating this, one gets $(T-\lambda)^n x = (T-\lambda)^{n-1} x = \dots = (T-\lambda) x = 0$ and this is a contradiction.

I don't know if it's what you look for, but the diagonalizability argument is not directly used, the basic step uses of course that T is symmetric, and this proof is, with minor changes, applicable for selfadjoint and dense defined Operators on Hilbert spaces.